# Firebase Database - Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to populate a label in my custom cell for my UITableViewController with information from my Firebase Database but I keep running into this error:

"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I did read this link: [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

I don't think I'm accessing outlets before they're loaded in and I did check that my IBOutlet connection is correct.

```
class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var postText: UILabel!

}

class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var postInfo = FeedCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
//         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

        self.tableView.rowHeight = 100.0

//        postText = UILabel()
//
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let cellRef = ref.child("post/body")

        cellRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let body = snapshot.value as? String {
                self.postInfo.postText.text = body
                print(body)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Here's my database]

I expected the label to be updated with the body text "test firebase" but I'm just running into that error. Is it because I defined my IBOutlet in another class then referenced it in my FeedTableVIewController? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: at first you should never access outlets directly, second create a model for the data, in the if statement populate array of type model with the data you would get from firebase and then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you configure cell with the data

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
var postInfo = FeedCell()
```

with

```
self.postInfo.postText.text = body <<< postText is nil
```

First you shouldn't create an instance var of a cell , and as your current var here `postInfo` is initated with `FeedCell()` so the outlet is nil regardless of it's connected / not

Second you should make use of table delegate and dataSource methods to populate your table